# How to update a binary component in a decompiled .swf file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, decompiling

I am working on a project which includes use of existing .swf files developed long time back by unknown resources.

I need to update one variable in the ActionScript. The actionscript is inside the binarydata folder and if i do any changes then the template gets corrupted or im not sure what but it does not display at all.

I have no experience working in flash hence requesting some guidance.

[image]

Comment: Option 1: https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/features/ Alternately, option 2, you can try this thread, it looks promising: https://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?343565-Swfmill-(or-similar)-for-AS3

Comment: Can you give a link for download the swf?And show the url you want to update.

Comment: @Pan thank you very much for your kind response. The same got fixed on my colleagues machine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue got fixed on a different machine and by using the JPEXS Decompiler.